# Environment variables not visible to java

Tags: c#, java, environment-variables

#### The project

The project is a large C# project which is used for test-automation. For this purpose i've to use a java-tool which is the tool which saves all results into a file which can be loaded into a test-environment.

#### The interface

I got a DLL from the vendor of the test-environment which is build in C++, this dll loads the java environment and loads the jar files.

#### Current situation

The java environment is loaded with success, its configured with environment-variables set in C# with this method:

```
String java = GetJavaInstallationPath();
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", String.Format("{0};{1}", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"), Path.Combine(java, @"bin\client")), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

After this i set the path to the java classes using this code:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ITEPCLASSPATH",
                String.Format("{0};{1}",
                Path.Combine(iTepPath, "itep.jar"),
                Path.Combine(iTepPath, "libs\\itorx.jar")), EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Which actually should work, it shows the correct value when using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ITEPCLASSPATH")` but the C++-DLL tells me that it isn't working.

When setting the class path by using a external bat-file it works. Some more facts:

- The application is started by the bat file
- The path is copied from my generated path of the dll
- I don't comment anything out, so the path is still set by C#

It seems that java is not accessing the env.-variable i set in C# but recognizes that i set it in the bat file.

I really need to set the variable via C#, how do i archive this?

Comment: a workaround could be to start the bat file from c# with `System.IO.Process.Start`. Do you really need to use the DLL? Otherwise, try to find out how the environment gets passed through dlls. I can't see why it doesn't work. I think it should.

Comment: @DarenThomas That's a workaround but would make a lot more work for me. :-/ And of course i have to use the DLL and don't have any access to the code of thoose DLL's.

Comment: When is the problematic DLL initialized? Maybe it reads the env. variables and remembers the values before you set the value in your code.

Comment: @Matej I initialize the DLL by using the Kernel32.dll-method `LoadLibrary` after i set all the variables.

Comment: Do you get the same output for Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables() in your C# app if it is started by the batch file/not by the batch file?

Comment: @Hans Tested it, they are the same when setting them by the bat and C#.

Comment: Could you show us how you set the environment variable in your batch file? Please remember setting an environment variable in a batch file like SET my_var="myvalue" means that the double quotes belong to the value.

Comment: @Hans Without quotes: `set ITEPCLASSPATH=D:\.....`

Comment: Did you try starting your C# app from the batch file but without setting your environment variable in the batch? Does it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not explicitly written in [Microsoft System.Environment documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes) but the target value `Process` seems to limit scope to the current process only. By default, [the CreateProcess method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inherits current process environment for the child process. Maybe the parameters used there breaks this default behavior.

So I propose you test first with `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` in `SetEnvironmentVariable` to see if it works better.

By the way, I think you will have to diagnose further environment variable and create process operations with tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

Comment: The process is the same but after setting the env. variable with different targets it works. But this still doesn't answer the question why it's working with a bat-file and not with `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` because a bat is limited to the current process only ( AFAIK ).

Comment: The process is not the same - the C# creates a child process to run the JVM, right ? The "bat" file will call the CreateProcess the "right way", I mean with default options so you get expected behavior: environment variables are inherited for the child process. The C# code may use alternate options with the consequence that the created JVM process as other environment variables. So my idea to diagnose with Process Monitor.

Comment: No there is only one process, the JVM run's in the same process than the C# process. I checked this.

Comment: So probably the JVM has loaded environment variables into a kind of cache before it has been changed by the C# code. In a normal usage, they are not supposed to change during process life. Have you tried Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable without target at all ? Have you track operations on environment variables with Process Monitor ?

Comment: The JVM is initialized after the variables are set. No i didn't, maybe i gonna try this out, but i think it targets to Process.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the environment variable works with each target: Process, User and Machine.  See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx) article.

```
// Set the environment variable for the default target (the current process).
Console.WriteLine(fmt2x, "(default)", myVarA, existsA);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(myVarA, existsA);

// Set the environment variable for the the current process.
Console.WriteLine(fmt2x, "Process", myVarB, existsB);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(myVarB, existsB, 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

// Set the environment variable for the the current user.
Console.WriteLine(fmt2x, "User", myVarC, existsC);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(myVarC, existsC, 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

// Set the environment variable for the the local machine.
Console.WriteLine(fmt2x, "Machine", myVarD, existsD);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(myVarD, existsD, 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java allows you to pass environment variables as parameters using the:

```
java -DMYPROP=MYVALUE myclass.class
```

argument syntax.  Check out the -D flag.

Those system properties then apply to that JVM process instance.  Wouldn't that be simpler than trying to modify the OS Environment?

Comment: If the java tool is third-party, you have to use the method(s) the implementors provided, no matter how good or bad they are.

Comment: By the way, the option -D set a system property in Java which is accessible with the same API than the environment variables...